# How can I remove time from date with Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

```
formatCalendarDate = function (dateTime) {
    return moment.utc(dateTime).format('LLL');
};
```

It displays: "28 februari 2013 09:24"

But I would like to remove the time at the end. How can I do that?

I'm using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 787, accepted):

Sorry to jump in so late, but if you want to *remove* the time portion of a `moment()` rather than *formatting* it, then the code is:

```
.startOf('day')
```

Ref: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/

Comment: Be careful with this if you're going between timezones (or if you're not paying attention to timezones). I had an issue where my UTC date was getting converted to local time, *then* applying `startOf('day')`, which was then the start of the *previous* day. Fixed with `moment(moment.utc('2013-10-29T00:00:00+00:00').startOf('day').format('LL')).startOf('day').toDate()`

Comment: Also be careful that this function actually mutates the original object

Comment: `.startOf('day')` does not removes the time part per se, it just sets the time to 00:00:00. So, yes, as commented by 'collin', you have to be careful when saving date. Better alternative is using `format('LL')`, as have been answered in this thread.

Comment: To avoid mutating the original object, use `someMoment.clone().startOf('day')` or `moment(someMoment).startOf('day')`.

Comment: Be careful, startOf('day') will reset everything and not just set the time to 00:00:00. `moment().utc().add(1,'d').startOf('day')` will reset the object to today.

Comment: I also had to deal with multiple timezones but found that simply stringing utc().startOf('day') was enough:

`moment("2017-10-09T00:00:00Z").isSameOrAfter(moment("2017-10-09 22:00:00+00:00").utc().startOf('day'), 'day');`

true

`moment("2017-10-09T00:00:00Z").isSameOrAfter(moment("2017-10-09 22:00:00+00:00").startOf('day'), 'day');`

false

Comment: This can be problematic with timezones, for example:
   `console.log(moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').startOf('day').format());` spits out `2018-03-09T00:00:00-08:00`

and `console.log(moment().startOf('day').format());` spits out
`2018-03-10T00:00:00+08:00`

Comment: @Tristan That's not accurate, `startOf('day')` changes the object to the start of the day it was already pointing at. Possibly converting to utc made the day shift to yesterday and then adding 1d brought it back to today

Answer (score 68):

#### Use `format('LL')`

Depending on what you're trying to do with it, `format('LL')` could do the trick. It produces something like this:

```
Moment().format('LL'); // => April 29, 2016
```

Comment: See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ for more formatting options.

Answer (score 47):

The correct way would be to specify the input as per your requirement which will give you more flexibility.

The present definition includes the following

`LTS  : 'h:mm:ss A',
 LT   : 'h:mm A',
 L    : 'MM/DD/YYYY',
 LL   : 'MMMM D, YYYY',
 LLL  : 'MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A',
 LLLL : 'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A'`

You can use any of these or change the input passed into moment().format().
For example, for your case you can pass `moment.utc(dateTime).format('MMMM D, YYYY')`.

Answer (score 33):

Okay, so I know I'm way late to the party. Like 6 years late but this was something I needed to figure out and have it formatted YYYY-MM-DD.

```
moment().format(moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE); // 2019-11-08
```

You can also pass in a parameter like, `2019-11-08T17:44:56.144`.

```
moment("2019-11-08T17:44:56.144").format(moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE); // 2019-11-08
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/

Answer (score 11):

```
formatCalendarDate = function (dateTime) {
    return moment.utc(dateTime).format('LL')
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use this format:

`moment().format('ddd, ll'); // Wed, Jan 4, 2017`

Answer (score 8):

With newer versions of moment.js you can also do this:

```
var dateTime = moment();

var dateValue = moment({
    year: dateTime.year(),
    month: dateTime.month(),
    day: dateTime.date()
});
```

See: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `date: dateTime.date()` instead of `day: dateTime.date()`?

Comment: 'day and date key both mean day-of-the-month.' from the docs. `day` works pre version 2.8.4.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever I use the `moment.js` library I specify the desired format this way:

```
moment(<your Date goes here>).format("DD-MMM-YYYY")
```

or

```
moment(<your Date goes here>).format("DD/MMM/YYYY")
```

... etc I hope you get the idea

Inside the format function, you put the desired format. The example above will get rid of all unwanted elements from the date such as minutes and seconds

Comment: This is not a good idea if you ever want to display your content in different locales. If you want to display dates in the correct format for the user's locale, you need to use one of the preset date formats (`L`, `LL`, etc.)

Comment: Why you set MMM three times.

Comment: MMM will give you the 3 first letters of the month.
'Apr'

MMMM will give you a full month name

Comment: Actually this is the best one if used with `DD/MM/YYYY` (two `M`s) as this doesn't break when comparing dates with different locales, the other variants fail.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this constructor

```
moment({h:0, m:0, s:0, ms:0})
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/

```js
console.log( moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') )

console.log( moment({h:0, m:0, s:0, ms:0}).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add some  ore description here

Comment: This is interesting! It's creating a moment and overriding hour, minutes and seconds but still keeping the underling date. Interesting because I would have guessed that `moment({h:0, m:0, s:0, ms:0})` would have given me January 1 1970 rather than today.

Comment: Also looks like `moment({ h: 0 })` does the same.

Comment: The docs say `Omitted units default to 0 or the current date, month, and year.`

Answer (score 5):

For people like me want the long date format (`LLLL`) but without the time of day, there's a GitHub issue for that: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2505. For now, there's a workaround:

```
var localeData = moment.localeData( moment.locale() ),
    llll = localeData.longDateFormat( 'llll' ),
    lll = localeData.longDateFormat( 'lll' ),
    ll = localeData.longDateFormat( 'll' ),
    longDateFormat = llll.replace( lll.replace( ll, '' ), '' );
var formattedDate = myMoment.format(longDateFormat);
```

Comment: Finally a sensible answer. Take my upvote sir! The issue hasn't been addressed yet it seems.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
moment.format().split("T")[0]
```

Comment: Watch out with this method, as `1993-06-07T22:00:00.000Z` will result as `1993-06-07` whereas it is the start of the day of `1993-06-08`

Answer (score 2):

The thing is - you can run into an issue with timezones. For example, if you parse date like this: `'2022-02-26T00:36:21+01:00'` it may turn into `'25/02/2022'` As a solution if your date is in ISO format you can just cut off the time portion from the string, like this:

```
moment('2022-02-26T00:36:21+01:00'.split('T')[0]).utc().format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

This solution is quite blunt, so be careful with string format.

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log( moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') )

console.log( moment({h:0, m:0, s:0, ms:0}).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new Date().toDateString()
```

Result - "Fri Jun 17 2022"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This format works pretty fine

```
const date = new Date();
const myFormat= 'YYYY-MM-DD';

const myDate = moment(date, 'YYYYMMDDTHHmmss').format(myFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

use Like this

```
moment().format("dd")
```

outPut : `"Tu"`

Answer (score -3):

```
moment(date).format(DateFormat)
```

Here DateFormat  should be `DateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD'`

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Consider making a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) understand how to answer questions. Please, give more information about your solution and use Stack Snippet to show your code.