# Remove time from date using javascript and pass it to excel

Tags: javascript, excel, date

I'm trying to do excel export using [alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql) and passing my date,**12 Apr 2018** by transforming using below function

```
    var dateStr = "12 Apr 2018";
    function trandformDate(dateString){ 
        var date = new Date(dateString);
        return new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
    }
    var date = trandformDate(dateStr);
```

When the excel gets generated I was able to see the date in **MM/DD/YYYY** format with the timezone.I would like to keep the date and removw timezone from excel.Please let me know how can I send time without timezone to excel so that the format remains the same ie., **MM/DD/YYYY**
 [image]

Comment: ..."with timezone"?  Do you mean "with the time"?

Comment: @ashleedawg I mean "with the time"

Comment: To confirm: you know how to get a datetime into Excel: `4/12/2018 6:30:00 PM` but you want to remove the time (so you have `4/12/2018`), and you want to do that in JavaScript, so this is *not* an Excel question, correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove time part from JavaScript date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722862/how-do-i-remove-time-part-from-javascript-date)

Comment: Don't put changes in comments, edit the question. It's very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by passing the date and setting timestamp to 0 using setUTC()

```
var dateStr = "12 Apr 2018";
transformDate(dateString) {
        const date = new Date(dateString);
        const timeStamp = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
        timeStamp.setUTCHours(0);
        timeStamp.setUTCMinutes(0);
        timeStamp.setMilliseconds(0);
        return timeStamp;
    }
var date = trandformDate(dateStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply split the array by space, and then use only the first part of the array.

```js
var date = new Date();
date = date.split(" ")[0];
```