# What is the best way to remove time text within a div with CSS or Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following div and  i want to remove the time e.g. **12:30**. What is the best way to do it? The content is dynamic. Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6gjhtLr/) i have tried

```
<div class="jsmatchdate">
11-08-2018 12:30 
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove time part from JavaScript date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722862/how-do-i-remove-time-part-from-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JQuery:

```
   $('.jsmatchdate').text( function (_,txt) {
     return txt.split(' ')[0];
   })
```

Explanation: we splitted text by ' ' (empty character)
split function returns an array of ['11-08-2018', '12:30'] and we need the first part with index 0.

Comment: why does the function need to accept two parameters? `function (_,txt)`

Comment: .text( function ) in JQuery documentation:  
Type: Function( Integer index, String text ) => String,    
a function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.... 
Source: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jQuery then you could try the slice command.

```
$('.jsmatchdate').text(function (_,txt) {
    return txt.slice(0, 11);
});
```

What this is doing is getting the text in the div and returning the desired length that you want, i.e. 11-08-2018

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/u6gjhtLr/7/)