# date type casting in npm package?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) npm package with my Nodejs server. I have a `datetime` field that I want to display without time but I do not want to convert the data type to `date`

So I did

```
select cast(dateReached as date) as date
```

Now if I run this in mysql workbench, I get the properly converted value. However, doing this using mysql package does not convert the datetime to time

```
pool.query("select cast(dateReached as date) as date",function(err,rows,fields){
   console.log(rows)
  //
})
```

Returns

> RowDataPacket {
>       Date: 2019-06-26T04:00:00.000Z }

Is there a way to cast date using the mysql package?

Answer (score 2):

It is returning **only date**, BUT it is being converted into `Date` object in Javascript which contains time.

You can,

1. Return `String` from DB, using: `dateStrings: true`, Refer [this](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/605) gihub issue for more information.

```
    const db = mysql.createConnection({ user: 'foo', password: 'bar', dateStrings: true });
```

2. Format the data After you get the `Date` object using the usual `Date` methods, like date's [day](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) / [month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) / [year](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear). Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722862/how-do-i-remove-time-part-from-javascript-date) answer for more information.