# Moment.js displaying date incorrectly

Tags: ruby, momentjs

I have a record which reads : `date: "2016-02-01 00:00:05`. However, when I do `moment(date).format("L")` the view renders `01/31/2016`. 
Any idea why? This happens which all dates, always one day before

Comment: Is there an offset in the timestamp? Looks like your issue is timezone based because the output of `format` is technically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130735/how-can-i-remove-time-from-my-date-with-moment-js). Auto-answering in case anybody runs into the same issue. As @bschaeffer said, it was a timezone problem, this fixed it:

```
moment.utc(date).format('L')
```

Comment: @MattJohnson, thanks for the feedback. Already added my fixed.