# Wrong output from new Date() function in enzyme test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs, enzyme

I am using the enzyme for testing my react app.
Now inside my app when I am running following command I am getting below output

Inside jsx file when I do console.log for below-mentioned line

```
Input  - new Date(moment().format('YYYY,MM,DD'))
Output - Wed Aug 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

But inside test cases when I am passing value defautlState

```
const defaultState = {
 dateToDisplay: new Date(moment().format('YYYY,MM,DD')),
};

it('shows slots on time scroller', () =>{
  const wrapper = shallow(<BookingDialogNew />);
  wrapper.setProps(defaultProps);
  wrapper.setState(defaultState);
});
```

I am getting output - `2017-08-29T18:30:00.000Z`

Not very good with moment and date, how to get output same as in the jsx file
Are there two line are same, please guide

Comment: `2017-08-29T18:30:00.000Z` is `Wed Aug 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` in UTC. The `Z` at the end mean the the time is in UTC. PS. I don't understand why you are using `new Date(moment().format('YYYY,MM,DD'))` instead of `new Date()`, moreover note that moment has [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method _to get a copy of the native Date object that Moment.js wraps_.

Comment: `new Date(moment().format('YYYY,MM,DD'))` makes no sense. It creates a date, outputs a string in "YYYY,MM,DD" format (e.g. "2017,08,31"), passes that to the Date constructor, which then attempts to parse the string. It is highly likely that the last parse will fail (it does in Safari at least). If you want a Date set to the start of the current day, then `moment().startOf('day').toDate()` will do the job.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*How can I remove time from date with Moment.js?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130735/how-can-i-remove-time-from-date-with-moment-js) BTW, "2017-08-29T18:30:00.000Z" and "Wed Aug 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530" are exactly the same moment in time. That is, Dates created with those strings will have exactly the same time value.